# Python: block network connections for testing purposes?

Tags: python, pytest, sandbox

I'm trying to test a package that provides interfaces to a few web services.  It has a test suite that is supposed to test most functions *without* connecting to the internet.  However, there are some lingering tests that may attempt to connect to the internet / download data, and I'd like to prevent them from doing so for two reasons: first, to make sure my test suite works if no network connection is available; second, so that I'm not spamming the web services with excess queries.

An obvious solution is to unplug my machine / turn off wireless, but when I'm running tests on a remote machine that obviously doesn't work.

So, my question: Can I block network / port access for a single python process?  ("sandbox" it, but just blocking network connections)

(AFAICT, pysandbox doesn't do this)

I'm using `py.test` so I need a solution that will work with `py.test`, in case that affects any proposed answers.

Comment: For those that may be looking for customisable blocking and / or recording the connections being made, you might be better off using [vcrpy](https://vcrpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/index.html). There's a [pytest plugin](https://pytest-vcr.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) for it.

Answer (score 47, accepted):

Monkey patching `socket` ought to do it:

```
import socket
def guard(*args, **kwargs):
    raise Exception("I told you not to use the Internet!")
socket.socket = guard
```

Make sure this runs before any other import.

Comment: This is great!  Any thoughts on how to get py.test to run this before anything else?

Comment: Answer to my last comment: run this in `conftests.py`.

Comment: There's a Py.test plugin for this now, so use that when you can. If not, you might be able to use `patch` on the `socket` method and pass `side_effect=Exception` as a parameter.

Comment: That's good solution, but it's worth noting that it affects only code that uses Python socket API. Code that calls system directly, eg. modules that wrap C libraries are unaffected by this.

Comment: I think patching the socket function is even a better solution, because it allows you to test with missing network connectivity for single test cases.

Comment: Neither this nor any of the below solutions work for many cases. Doesn't even seem to stop the requests library.

Comment: This small handy solution needs to be a class in Python 3.8, wherein the __init__ call raises the error, but works well for Python based URL calls.

Comment: For python 3 I used `socket.socket.connect = guard` and it all worked as expected. I think using a pytest fixture and `autouse=True` is safer.

Comment: This approach can be too aggressive, because it breaks even simple imports such as `import urllib.request`. Alternative solution: https://stackoverflow.com/a/77603390/263061

Answer (score 28):

**Update**: There is now a pytest plugin that does the same thing as this answer! You can read the answer just to see how things work, but I **strongly** recommend using the plugin instead of copying-pasting my answer :-) See here: https://github.com/miketheman/pytest-socket

---

I found Thomas Orozco's answer to be very helpful. Following on keflavich, this is how I integrated into my unit test suite. This works for me with thousands of very different unit test-cases (<100 that need socket though) ... and in and out of doctests.

I posted it [here](https://gist.github.com/hangtwenty/9200597e3be274c79896). Including below for convenience. Tested with Python 2.7.5, pytest==2.7.0. (To test for yourself, run `py.test --doctest-modules` in directory with all 3 files cloned.)

**_socket_toggle.py**

```
from __future__ import print_function
import socket
import sys

_module = sys.modules[__name__]

def disable_socket():
    """ disable socket.socket to disable the Internet. useful in testing.

    .. doctest::
        >>> enable_socket()
        [!] socket.socket is enabled.
        >>> disable_socket()
        [!] socket.socket is disabled. Welcome to the desert of the real.
        >>> socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
        Traceback (most recent call last):
        ...
        RuntimeError: I told you not to use the Internet!
        >>> enable_socket()
        [!] socket.socket is enabled.
        >>> enable_socket()
        [!] socket.socket is enabled.
        >>> disable_socket()
        [!] socket.socket is disabled. Welcome to the desert of the real.
        >>> socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
        Traceback (most recent call last):
        ...
        RuntimeError: I told you not to use the Internet!
        >>> enable_socket()
        [!] socket.socket is enabled.
    """
    setattr(_module, '_socket_disabled', True)

    def guarded(*args, **kwargs):
        if getattr(_module, '_socket_disabled', False):
            raise RuntimeError("I told you not to use the Internet!")
        else:
            # SocketType is a valid public alias of socket.socket,
            # we use it here to avoid namespace collisions
            return socket.SocketType(*args, **kwargs)

    socket.socket = guarded

    print(u'[!] socket.socket is disabled. Welcome to the desert of the real.')


def enable_socket():
    """ re-enable socket.socket to enable the Internet. useful in testing.
    """
    setattr(_module, '_socket_disabled', False)
    print(u'[!] socket.socket is enabled.')
```

**conftest.py**

```
# Put this in the conftest.py at the top of your unit tests folder,
# so it's available to all unit tests
import pytest
import _socket_toggle


def pytest_runtest_setup():
    """ disable the interet. test-cases can explicitly re-enable """
    _socket_toggle.disable_socket()


@pytest.fixture(scope='function')
def enable_socket(request):
    """ re-enable socket.socket for duration of this test function """
    _socket_toggle.enable_socket()
    request.addfinalizer(_socket_toggle.disable_socket)
```

**test_example.py**

```
# Example usage of the py.test fixture in tests
import socket
import pytest

try:
    from urllib2 import urlopen
except ImportError:
    import urllib3
    urlopen = urllib.request.urlopen


def test_socket_disabled_by_default():
    # default behavior: socket.socket is unusable
    with pytest.raises(RuntimeError):
        urlopen(u'https://www.python.org/')


def test_explicitly_enable_socket(enable_socket):
    # socket is enabled by pytest fixture from conftest. disabled in finalizer
    assert socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
```

Comment: Why not raising a `ConnectionError` exception ?

Comment: @FemtoTrader I suppose because that's _too_ correct. Don't want to confuse the error we are throwing, with the error that a built-in would throw, for a legitimate `ConnectionError`. In practice I actually use a subclass of Runtime Error but I wanted to keep this example simpler

Comment: Any chance of an update to this that works for Python3? I'd also be happy to help turn this into a pytest plugin.

Comment: @MikeFiedler I've updated the answer to link to your plugin. Great work!

Comment: brilliant work. With the way we've got our tests setup, this is a good additional check to add

Answer (score 3):

Building on the very helpful answers from Thomas Orozco and driftcatcher here is a variant that works with Python's unittest and (after a small change) Django.

All you need to do is inherit your test case class from the enhanced `NoSocketTestCase` class and any access to the network will be detected and raises the `SocketAccessError` exception.

And this approach also works with Django. You only need to change the `NoSocketTestCase` class to inherit from `django.test.TestCase` instead of `unittest.TestCase`.

While not strictly answering OP's question I think this might be helpful for anyone who wants to block network access in unit tests.

### no_sockets.py

```
import socket
from unittest import TestCase


class SocketAccessError(Exception):
    pass


class NoSocketsTestCase(TestCase):
    """Enhancement of TestCase class that prevents any use of sockets

    Will throw the exception SocketAccessError when any code tries to
    access network sockets
    """

    @classmethod
    def setUpClass(cls):
        cls.socket_original = socket.socket
        socket.socket = cls.guard
        return super().setUpClass()

    @classmethod
    def tearDownClass(cls):
        socket.socket = cls.socket_original
        return super().tearDownClass()

    @staticmethod
    def guard(*args, **kwargs):
        raise SocketAccessError('Attempted to access network')
```

### test_no_sockets.py

```
import urllib.request
from .no_sockets import NoSocketsTestCase, SocketAccessError


class TestNoSocketsTestCase(NoSocketsTestCase):

    def test_raises_exception_on_attempted_network_access(self):

        with self.assertRaises(SocketAccessError):            
            urllib.request.urlopen('https://www.google.com')
```

Answer (score 1):

A simple way to put a gag on the `requests` library:

```py
from unittest import mock

requests_gag = mock.patch(
    'requests.Session.request',
    mock.Mock(side_effect=RuntimeError(
        'Please use the `responses` library to mock HTTP in your tests.'
    ))
)

with requests_gag:
    ...  # no Internet here
```

Answer (score 1):

The approach suggested by other answers (replacing `socket.socket`) is **too aggressive** (see below).

You can use Python's `audit` functionality to prevent calls to [`socket.connect()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/socket.html#socket.socket.connect):

```py
import socket
import sys

deny_connects = False

def deny_nework_connections():
  global deny_connects

  def audit_hook_deny_connects(event: str, args):
    if deny_connects and event == 'socket.connect':
      sock: socket.socket = args[0]
      if sock.family != socket.AddressFamily.AF_UNIX:
        raise Exception("network connection denied to prevent accidental Internet access")

  deny_connects = True
  sys.addaudithook(audit_hook_deny_connects)
```

If you then want to later allow network connections again, set `deny_connects = True`.

(Audit hooks seem to be irremovable, thus the global boolean.)

The [audit events table](https://docs.python.org/3/library/audit_events.html) shows what events you can intercept.

---

The approach suggested by other answers (replacing `socket.socket`) is too aggressive because it creates false positives even for the most benign actions such as `import`.

Example: `import urllib.request` creates stack trace:

```
...
  File "python3.10/urllib/request.py", line 88, in <module>
    import http.client
  File "python3.10/http/client.py", line 1395, in <module>
    import ssl
  File "python3.10/ssl.py", line 1002, in <module>
    class SSLSocket(socket):
TypeError: function() argument 'code' must be code, not str
```

Answer (score 0):

[`httpretty`](https://github.com/gabrielfalcao/HTTPretty) is a small library that solves this problem.

If you are using Django test runner, write a custom test runner where you disable all 3rd party API calls.

```py
# common/test_runner.py

import httpretty
from django.test.runner import DiscoverRunner


class CustomTestRunner(DiscoverRunner):
    def run_tests(self, *args, **kwargs):
        with httpretty.enabled(allow_net_connect=False):
            return super().run_tests(*args, **kwargs)
```

add this new test runner to your settings

```py
TEST_RUNNER = "common.test_runner.CustomTestRunner"
```

And from now on all external API calls have to be mocked or `httpretty.errors.UnmockedError` will be raised.

If you are using pytest, this fixture should work.

```
@pytest.fixture
def disable_external_api_calls():
    httpretty.enable()
    yield
    httpretty.disable()
```

Answer (score 0):

I have a pytest solution. `pytest-network` lybrary help me on this.

```py
# conftest.py
import pytest
import socket

_original_connect = socket.socket.connect

def patched_connect(*args, **kwargs):
    ...
    # It depends on your testing purpose
    # You may want a exception, add here
    # If you test unconnectable situations
    # it can stay like this 
    

@pytest.fixture
def enable_network():
    socket.socket.connect = _original_connect
    yield
    socket.socket.connect = patched_connect

@pytest.fixture
def disable_network():
    socket.socket.connect = patched_connect
    yield
    socket.socket.connect = _original_connect
```

```py
# test_internet.py
def test_your_unconnectable_situation(disable_network):
    response = request.get('http://stackoverflow.com/')
    response.status_code == 400
```

Answer (score 0):

Other answers break tests that just create local threads, like pytorch dataloaders. If you want to allow localhost internet connections as well, you can try this code.

```py
    import socket
    orig_connect = socket.socket.connect
    def guard(self, address: tuple, *args: Any, **kwargs: Any) -> None:
        is_local_connection = False
        # Family types documeted at https://docs.python.org/3/library/socket.html#socket-families
        if self.family == socket.AF_UNIX:
            # AF_UNIX is for local connections only
            is_local_connection = True
        elif self.family == socket.AF_INET or self.family == socket.AF_INET6:
            # Check that the host is local
            host = address[0]
            is_local_connection = host  == 'localhost' or host == '127.0.0.1'
        else:
            # Other types are too rare to bother with (e.g. cluster computing)
            pass
        if is_local_connection:
            orig_connect(self, address, *args, **kwargs)
        else:
            assert False, "No internet allowed in unittests"
    socket.socket.connect = guard
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use https://github.com/miketheman/pytest-socket .

then run tests with

```
poetry run pytest --disable-socket testfilename.py
```