# Disable in tests outbound network connections except to localhost

Tags: python, python-3.x, http, networking

I want to be sure that none of tests make external network connections by prohibiting such connections.

There is a [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18601828/python-block-network-connections-for-testing-purposes) to block all connections, but my tests use a local database.

So I am looking for a way to block all outbound TCP connections except to `localhost`.

Comment: Do you use a specific lib/util for the connections? If so, you could mock patch it.