# Block network connections other than to localhost

Tags: python, sockets, testing, networking

I want to ensure that my tests don't use third-party services when they are run.

These [answers](https://stackoverflow.com/q/18601828/248296) cover the case when no connections are possible at all.

I want to be able to make TCP connections to the local database (one of the cases).

How to patch Python runtime to allow TCP connections to localhost (or a given host, ideally to the specified ports)?

Comment: Based on the answers in your linked question, I believe writing a test in the mock of `socket.socket` to check if your address is localhost (and forward to the real `socket.socket`) or raise an exception should be relatively straightforward

Comment: I tried it to do this some time ago. I don't remember exactly why,  but it didn't work that easy.

Answer (score 1):

[pytest-socket](https://github.com/miketheman/pytest-socket) allows disabling socket altogether or allow connections only to specified hosts.